# Atomic operations in Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize, so I have a very simple, perhaps trivial question. Consider the example on the docs:

```
var project = Project.build({
  title: 'my awesome project',
  description: 'woot woot. this will make me a rich man'
})

var task = Task.build({
  title: 'specify the project idea',
  description: 'bla',
  deadline: new Date()
})
```

I want to make sure I either save both or none of them. How do I do that?
In other words, how do I atomically perform creat/update operations on multiple tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, use transactions:

```
sequelize.transaction().then(function (t) {
    return sequelize.Promise.all([
      Project.create({
        title: 'my awesome project',
        description: 'woot woot. this will make me a rich man'
      }, { transaction: t }), 
      Task.build({
        title: 'specify the project idea',
        description: 'bla',
        deadline: new Date()
      }, { transaction: t })
    ]).then(function onFulfilled (project, task) {
        return t.commit();
    }, function onRejected(err) {
        return t.rollback();
    });
});
```

In the latest version (2.0-rc2) this can also be written more succinctly as:

```
sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    return sequelize.Promise.all([
      Project.create({
        title: 'my awesome project',
        description: 'woot woot. this will make me a rich man'
      }, { transaction: t }), 
      Task.build({
        title: 'specify the project idea',
        description: 'bla',
        deadline: new Date()
      }, { transaction: t })
    ]);
});
```

By passing a callback to the `transaction` instead of calling `then`. The callback returns a promsie chain, and the transaction is commited or rolled back, depending on the success of the returned promise. Meaning that if any of the operations passed to `Promise.all` fail, the transaction will be rolled back.